# Improving performance of PhoneGap application on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

i am new to phonegap i want to know how can i improve performance of my app created using phonegap. Key issue is when the app starts up it is very slow on emulator as well as on device. When the app starts it first shows native android activity UI then the webview is invoked. Why this transition is happening and how i can hide from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are talking about splashscreen.

Im going to give you a lot of general answers, hope that some of them can help you.

You can extend the "splashscreen" life time by using the config.xml file, check this:

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml#android-prefs

Simon made a post about Android Splash Screens:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.dk/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html

Or read some here:

[Black screen for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994717/black-screen-for-android-app)