# How to remove the first blank page in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I'm not sure if it is called "splashscreen"? May I ask how can I avoid that when I open the app, it will load 0.5-1 second on that blank screen, then redirect to my indext.html??

Comment: this might help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994717/black-screen-for-android-app

Answer (score 1):

If you see the following docs it details how to setup a custom splash screen to show when the app is loading.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

If you use the "navigator.splashscreen.hide();" function you can ensure that your app has completely loaded before hiding the splash screen. (Don't forget to change the AutoHideSplashScreen setting on iOS if you do this)

Comment: do it mean that i simply add navigator.splashscreen.hide(); in index page? it seems not work, still can see the blank page when first load app

Comment: You need to call that after the page has rendered, depending on how your app is setup you might have to cheat and use a timeout with a guess on how long it takes to render.

You also need to add some code to get it to work in android and change one of the cordova settings in iOS, both are detailed on the docs link.